# CSS - original vs. custom style sheet - correct way to overwrite styles

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using a WordPress theme that uses its own styling of the buttons. The following lines are the part of the CSS :

```
.button {
   background: #333 !important;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#333), to(#222))  !important;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#333, #222) !important;
}
```

I am using my own custom style sheet and I would like to overwrite these styles, but all I need to do is to change the background color and remove the gradient.

If I only keep the line changing the background color in my style sheet like this :

```
.button {
   background: #353535 !important;
}
```

Then the gradient is still displaying because it is in the original stylesheet.

If I set the gradient lines as `background: none;` then it will affect the first line where I changed the color, so nothing will display.

So I have done it this way instead :

```
.button {
    background: #353535 !important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#), to(#))  !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#, #) !important;
}
```

I removed the gradient colors.

It works, but this is probably not the way to do this.

Is there a proper way to remove the gradient styles in a custom css style sheet ??

Comment: "then the gradient is still displaying, because it is in the original stylesheet" That is not supposed to happen, unless the original stylesheet is being loaded *after* your custom stylesheet.

Comment: I have now removed it from the custom style sheet and all seems to work. hmm, not sure, must have done something wrong before. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML/CSS perspective: gradients are not colors but images.

Thus just remove the background-image.

```
background-image: none;
```